# Instagram token

Tags: token, instagram

I am new in this field . 
I m trying to get access token for parsing app I use http://localhost as web site link . As a result I got this error 
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

I don't have site but I need access token

Comment: Have you registered `http://localhost:<port>` in the instagram developer portal?

Comment: yes https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/98079d3efb2c4a259f4cfe22add36a5e/